# No targets specified and no makefile found RedisGraph build on OS X

Tags: c++, makefile, redisgraph

I am trying to install RedisGraph on my Macbook Pro. I have clone the repo and in the project directory I ran the `make` command but I get the following output.

```
make[2]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [../deps/rax/rax.o] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

There's a Makefile in the repo though. If I run `make Makefile`, I still get

```
make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'.
```

My gcc version:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I am following the steps on [this doc](https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph#building). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Not sure if it is related to OS X version of Clang (if I have to change it to a different version).

Comment: There is probably a project configuration step that you've skipped.  Details would depend on the project, but such a step would analyze the system and create an appropriate makefile.  Dunno whether that's covered in the build documentation, because you provided a bad link to the doc you say you are following.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the post with the right link.

Comment: The instructions give a specific command to use to clone the repository.  Did you use it?  Especially, did you include the `--recurse-submodules` option when you cloned?  If you did, and everything was successful, then the `deps` subdirectory should contain several subdirectories containing source distributions of other projects.  The `make` diagnostic you received seems to indicate that one or more of those is missing or incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repo, you must clone its submodules with `git submodule update --init --recursive` . Then make will execute properly.